# Yii2 ActiveRecord model with dynamic fields? php

Tags: php, database, yii2, models, active-form

Hello everyone and thank you for your help.

There is a problem with which I can not cope on my own, but for you, I'll give it an example of multilanguage.
[image]

We have 3 tables in the database:

- **page** -> page_id(*primary*), date_create
- **page_lang** -> related_id, page_id, lang_id, title, excerpt, content
- **lang** -> lang_id, name, local, url

---

** Example data: **

```
page = { page_id: 3, date_create: 1520209219 }
page_lang = { related_id : 5, page_id : 3, lang_id : 1, title: 'some title en', excerpt: 'some quote en', content: 'some text en'}
page_lang = { related_id : 6, page_id : 3, lang_id : 2, title: 'some title ua', excerpt: 'some quote ua', content: 'some text ua'}
page_lang = { related_id : 7, page_id : 3, lang_id : 3, title: 'some title pl', excerpt: 'some quote pl', content: 'some text pl'}
lang = { lang_id : 1, name: 'English', local : 'en-GB', url : 'en'}
lang = { lang_id : 2, name: 'Ukrainian', local : 'ua-UA', url : 'ua'}
lang = { lang_id : 3, name: 'Polish', local : 'en-GB', url : 'pl'}
```

---

How to make ActiveRecord model in YII2 dependencies between them ...

That we in the admin panel could edit one page
All this data and they were saved without additional *crutches* in the save () method.

ActiveForm generates fields as

```
<?= $form->field($page, 'date_create')->textInput() ?>
return <input name="Page[date_create]" ...>
```

Of course, for other models in the base format, this is the case:

```
<?= $form->field($pagelang, 'title')->textInput() ?>
<input name="PageLang[title]" ...>
```

but we have two different models - two different forms, and I can not **save()** them together and coherently

How to combine the data into one form*(one, main model?)* - *I do not understand, and I want to deal with it. I hope for your help.*

Referring to the "*crutches*" to Yii2, then it looks so

```
// without $form->field(...)
<input name="Page[PageLang][<?php echo $lang->id; ?>][name]" ...>
```

and in $model->save() example...

```
...
$data = Yii::$app->request->post( 'Page' );

foreach( $data['PageLang'] as $key => $lang ) {
    // $key = LANG_ID;
    // $lang = { name: _value_, excerpt: _value_, content: _value_ };
    $pagelang = new PageLang()
    $pagelang->title = $lang['title'];
    // ... 
    $pagelang->save();
}
...
```

but I would like it to work in a normal way.
Without crutches, not safe solutions.

Thx.

Comment: You may create a `form` which extends `yii\base\Model`. The `form` contains all the attributes which being contained in your `Page` and `PageLang`. Then all the data could be collected in the fake `form`. After validating the data, you can save them in your `Page` and `PageLang` respectively.

Comment: Hi. I recommend to use [TranslateableBehavior](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-translateable-behavior)

Comment: Use FormModel i.e Extend your custom model class with `yii\base\model` and add all the fields as @paul mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This solution helps to link {Page} and {PageLang}.

- **Github** : [OmgDef/yii2-multilingual-behavior](https://github.com/OmgDef/yii2-multilingual-behavior)

Of course, the link {PageLang.lang_id} with the {Languages.id} table **is not**.
 (Tables 'pageLang', 'languages' not related)

---

But, we have a field {PageLang.language} with the **code of the language** (string) and if necessary, they can be associated with {Languages}, then do not bind.